# Play a video with subtitles in beamer presentation using Pdfpc

Tags: beamer, video

I have recently discovered the powerful and really convenient [`pdfpc` presenter tool](https://pdfpc.github.io/). An important feature is that it allows to have embedded video using simple hyperlinks. I wonder if this would be possible to have a video played with its associated subtitles, in case we have a `.srt` file with the same name (as VLC does, for example).

Let's say I have two files : `Myvideo.avi` (video file) and `Myvideo.srt` (subtitle file), I would like to have `pdfpc` play video together with the subtitles. Is it possible?

Comment: I do not know about the possibility with pdfpc, but what prevents you from producing a second video with subtitles (or even add the subtitles to the first video as an overlay)? That would be beamer and viewer compatible.

Comment: Yes, it could be a workaround, but it is heavier, and less adaptable (especially if one want to take into account several languages).